# Put words, separated by commas, in quotes

Tags: vim, vi

I have a long line of words, looking like this:

```
foo,foo bar,bar@foo,foo# bar,bar$ foo#
```

Now I would like to turn it into:

```
"foo","foo bar","bar@foo","foo# bar","bar$ foo#"
```

Thus, the delimiter is a comma.
What is the best way to do this in `vi(m)`?

**EDIT**:
Would anyone care to elaborate on the downvotes?

Comment: Yes, there are people who are downvoting questions and answers in my opinion without any reason, like yours. What's wrong with your question? I don't know. Its i.m.o. a correct question.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is "what have you tried" - but this question doesn't really lend itself to that sort of process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to work. Capture everything thats not a comma and replace it with the captured part in quotes. The `g` at the end of the command says replace all instances that match the regex on the line. Without the `g` it would only match the first one. Take a look at `:h :s` and`:h :s_flags`

```
:%s/\([^,]\+\)/"\1"/g
```

Input:

```
foo,foo bar,bar@foo,foo# bar,bar$ foo#
```

Output:

```
"foo","foo bar","bar@foo","foo# bar","bar$ foo#"
```

Comment: Am I doing anything wrong? When I insert your command, it only surrounds the first word with quotes and leaves the rest as is. My result: `"foo",foo bar,bar@foo,foo# bar,bar$ foo#`

Comment: @cherrun did you forget the `g` at the end?

Comment: @FDinoff No, definitely had the `g`. I also tried adding a `c` to see which words it actually looks for and it only suggested that the first word is matching the pattern.

Comment: @cherrun I just tried my solution again (copy and paste) on your test string and I get the output I have posted above. What exactly are you typing in? or are you testing it on a different string?

Comment: @FDinoff No, I actually just copied the input and applied the command. Nothing changed whatsoever. One string, in one line. I even tried with a completely empty `vimrc` file. So it has nothing to do with my config file either. Don't know how it works on your end.

Comment: @FDinoff Oh wait. I had to open up a new file with the empty config file. Now it works. I guess I have something in my `vimrc` file that messes the command up.

Comment: @cherrun Great now you just need to figure out what is messing it up I guess. One way is just to do a binary search on your vimrc to find the offending lines.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do simple stuff in vim is to use macros; it takes shorter time than learning how to define functions or figuring out a search and replace pattern.

In command mode,
Move your cursor to the start of the line `0`
Start recording the macro as macro a `qa`
Insert a quotation mark `i"`
Move to a colon or end of line `/.,\|$` `<Enter>`
Append a quotation mark `a"`
Move to the beginning of the next cell `ll`
Stop recording the macro `q`

Now you have converted the first cell and have recorded a macro. To convert another cell `@a` (or `@@` which means run last used macro). Once you reach the end of a line, move to the beginning of the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for l in range( 1, line('$') ) | 
  call append( line('.') - 1, join( map( split( getline('.'), ',' ), '"\"" . v:val . "\""' ), ',' ) ) | 
  delete | 
endfor
```

**Explanation**:

For each line split line with comma, add a leading and trailing double quote using `map` function, join them with comma and append it above current line, and then delete current cursor line, that will be the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the start and end of the string, `s/,/","/g` would do. So I suppose it all depends on whether you are looking for a quick-and-dirty hack  to get the job done once, or whether you expect this to be a job that you need to repeat a lot.